# Parsing XML file from the end of file

Tags: java, xml

I want to use XML for storing some data. But I do not want read full file when I want to get the last data that was inserted there, as well as I do not want to rewrite full file when adding new data there. Is there a standard way in java to parse xml file not from the beginning but from the end. So that for example SAX or StaX parser will first encounter last closing root tag and than last tag. Or if I want to do this I should read and write everything  like I am reading/writing regular text file?

Comment: Couldn't you just add New data to the front of the file? XML would not be the best format for that but with a rather flat structure and some playing with Offsets you could achieve what you want. Just want to point out that you define semantics, that is if newest entry goes 1st or last in your data structure

Comment: If I will be adding new data in front of the file than I will have rewrite the whole file to save it. Read operation is good but write is equal to creating new same file.

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally, XML is a poor representation choice for this. The format is inherently "contained" like this, and I haven't seen any APIs which encourage you to fight against that.

Options:

- Choose a different format entirely (e.g. use a database)
- Create lots of small XML files instead - each one self-contained. When you want the whole of the data, read all the files
- Just swallow the hit and read/write the whole file each time.

Comment: How do you think, will it be efficient to create a lot of xml files and put them all in one zip. Will I be able to read separate files from zip without unpacking the whole zip but only one file that I need?

Comment: @trims: Yes, that would be reasonably efficient for reading (assuming a decent zip implementation) - but you wouldn't want to have to repack the zip file every time you added a new entry.

Answer (score 1):

I found a good topic on this with example solutions for what I want.
This link: http://www.oreillynet.com/xml/blog/2007/03/parsing_xml_backwards.html
Seems that XML is not good file format to achieve what I want. There is no standard parser that can parse XML from the end instead of beginning.

Probably the best solution for will be storing all xml data in one file that contains composition of many xml files contents. On each line stored separate contents of XML. The file itself is not well formed XML but each line contains well formed xml that I will parse using standard xml parser(StaX).

This way I will be able to read just lines from the end of file and append new data to the end of file. When I need the whole data or only the part of it I will read all line or part of them. Probably I can also implement pagination from the end of file for that because the file can be big.

Why XML in each line? I think it is easy to use API for parsing it as well as it is human readable to store data in xml instead of just separating values in the line with some symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use sax/stax and simply process only your last entry? Yes, it will need to open and go through the whole file, but at least it's fairly efficient as opposed to loading the whole DOM tree.

Short of doing that, I don't think you can do what you're asking using XML as a source.

**Another alternative**, apart from the ones provided by Jon Skeet in his answer, would be to keep the same format but insert the latest entries first, and stop processing the files as soon as you've read your entry.

Comment: If the file is big than reading the whole find to find only the latest line would be very inefficient. Yes it much better than loading the whole file in memory but still very inefficient for getting only one line.
Another alternative I believe is even less efficient because when inserting something at the beginning of the file I will have to rewrite the whole file.
Maybe xml is not the best format for what I want.

Comment: @trims: probably not. You could also consider implementing your own XML parser and using a memory-mapped file, but that means quite a lot of headaches for you. I guess if you don't need any sort of schema validation and your format is pretty fixed this could be a solution, but it kinda points out again that XML isn't what you want.